# Insert Method as part of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

This method has been plaguing me for hours. It's part of an `array` of type X that should take any datatype.  This is the first time I've worked on a generic type `array` and a debugger as well.

The errors I'm getting from testing are:

```
expected: 'hello' but was 'null' and 
0: ...ArrayOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

It also looks like the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` handling isn't being thrown correctly either.

I have no idea what to do.  My remove function seems to be working fine.

```
public void insert( int index, X item )
{
    if ( index > 0 || index < length )
    {
        length++;
        X[] obj2 = (X[]) new Object[obj.length - 1];
        for ( int i = 0; i == index; i++ )
        {
            obj2[i] = obj[i];
        }
        obj2[index] = item;
        for ( int i = index; i == length; i++ )
        {
            obj2[i + 1] = obj[i];
        }
        obj = obj2;
    }

    else
    {
        throw new java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("" + index);
    }
}

@Test
public void testInsert()
{
    XArray<String> b = new XArray<String>();
    b.add("hello");
    b.add("bye");
    b.insert(1, "adios");
    assertEquals("hello", b.get(0));
    assertEquals("adios", b.get(1));
    assertEquals("bye", b.get(2));
    assertEquals(3, b.size());

    b.insert(1, "buenos dias");
    assertEquals(4, b.size());
    assertEquals("hello", b.get(0));
    assertEquals("buenos dias", b.get(1));
    assertEquals("adios", b.get(2));

    b.insert(0, "hi");
    assertEquals(5, b.size());
    assertEquals("hi", b.get(0));
    assertEquals("hello", b.get(1));

    b.insert(4, "see ya");
    assertEquals(6, b.size());
    assertEquals("see ya", b.get(4));
    assertEquals("bye", b.get(5));
}
```

Comment: What to do : First thing first : Indent your code correctly.

Comment: When your  `index` is equal to `0` you are throwing a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, you are not handling it!

Comment: @dsorenson Please ask the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems.

1) Assuming that `length` is an instance variable, which reflects the `length` of the `obj` array, then you actually want to do the following test:

```
if (index >= 0 && index <= length)
```

This tests to see if your *new* item index is either 0 or more, or is 1 greater than the maximum index in your current `obj` array (i.e., equal to the current array length). *This does depend slightly on your expected contract* I think it's reasonable to expect that you can "insert" at the end of the list, but you may have to restrict it to only inserting in the middle, and therefore only if there is another element. In this case you want

```
if (length > 0 && index >= 0 && index < length)
```

Note: you test `&&`, not `||` as you need all conditions to be true. If you wanted to do a more standard argument validity check at the beginning you could do:

```
    if (index < 0 || index > length)
      throw new java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("" + index);
```

This has the benefit of removing the need for an `else` block and reducing your code nesting slightly.

2) You then increment `this.length`, but then you do `new Object[obj.length - 1];`, which makes no sense. I suspect you want to do:

```
  length++;
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  X[] obj2 = (X[]) new Object[this.length];
```

or better still:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  X[] obj2 = (X[]) new Object[++length];
```

3) Your first loop does `for ( int i = 0; i == index; i++ )`, which should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
```

This is because a loop condition statement doesn't test for the breakout condition (i.e. stop when this is true) but for the continuation condition (i.e. continue while `i` is less than `index`)

4) Your second loop does `for ( int i = index; i == length; i++ )`, and should do:

```
for (int i = index; i < length - 1; i++)
```

This is because your length has increased, but you are using `i` to refer to the original array indexes, not the larger array indexes.

All in all I think it looks like the code below.

The biggest issue here is probably your approach to the testing. You have several tests inside one mega-test. That doesn't help you isolate the individual errors and work out what is wrong with your method without breaking out the debugger (pun not intended, but I just saw it so I'll leave it). Ideally you shouldn't have to use the debugger if your unit tests are small, focused, and isolated. Examples of such tests are included at the end.

```
class XArray<X> {
  private int length;
  private X[] obj;
  public XArray() {
    this.obj = initBackingArray(0);
    this.length = 0;
  }
  private X[] initBackingArray(int length) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    X[] result = (X[])new Object[length];
    return result;
  }
  public X get(int index) {
    return this.obj[index];
  }
  public int size() {
    return this.length;
  }
  public void add(X item) {
    insert(length, item);
  }
  public void insert( int index, X item )
  {
    if (index >= 0 && index <= length)
    {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      X[] obj2 = (X[]) new Object[++length];
      for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
      {
        obj2[i] = obj[i];
      }
      obj2[index] = item;
      for (int i = index; i < length - 1; i++)
      {
        obj2[i+1] = obj[i];
      }
      obj = obj2;
    }

    else
    {
      throw new java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("" + index);
    }
  }
}
```

Example tests:

```
@Test
public void testAddOnceWorks()   {
    XArray<String> b = new XArray<String>();
    b.add("hello");
}
@Test
public void testAddTwiceWorks()   {
    XArray<String> b = new XArray<String>();
    b.add("hello");
    b.add("bye");
}
@Test
public void testInsertOnEmptyWorks()   {
    XArray<String> b = new XArray<String>();
    b.insert(0, "hello");
}
@Test
public void testAddOnceInsertBeforeWorks()   {
    XArray<String> b = new XArray<String>();
    b.add("hello");
    b.insert(0, "hello");
}
```

Comment: I like these these tests, because you can reduce your code to `public void add(X item) { return; }` and `public void insert(int index, X item) { return; }` :D.

Comment: @Tom. Indeed, although "*adds a valid input and doesn't throw*" is a necessary test of a contract as per the OP's mega-test (and in fact [true TDD](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd)). That the OP should also test "*adds an invalid input and throws*", and "*adds an input, and returns it from that index*" is indisputable but my point was not to write out every test the OP would need to test the class contract as it was not specified (and it would take too long).

Comment: @AndyBrown Thank you for the help.  I had kept trying so many different things that I just posted my code at the time.  I went as far as doing things that I didn't think would work.  The answer also helped me correct a similar problem with my remove function that I hadn't found previously.  Thanks for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, your logic for bounds checking is incorrect.  Every value possible for `index` is either greater than `0` *or* less than `length`.  This causes the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you are trying to create not to be thrown.  (It's possible Java may throw its own AIOOBE if you do access your array out of bounds.)

You should ensure that both conditions are met.  Use `&&` instead of `||`.

```
if ( index > 0 && index < length )
```

Also, when copying old elements to your new array, you need to realize that the `for` loop condition being `true` means "keep going", not "stop".  Keep looping while the `index` has not reached `length` yet.  Change `==` to `<`.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < index; i++ )
```

(A similar change is needed for the other `for` loop.)

Comment: You're right, thanks for your help!  I was kind of in the middle of either trying to throw it before getting to the for loop or nesting the for loop but my brain had turned to mush.